# CSS : Gap between DIV and Text using float?

Tags: css

I have been developing a website today and successfully got the text to wrap around the divs which I'm using for images. Whilst it has worked, there isn't a gap between the border of the div and the start of the text. The divs only contain the following

{float: left;}

Is there anyway to fix it so there is a gap between the side-border of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having any code to work with, I'm going to assume this is what you're looking for:

What you probably need is to use a margin around the divs. A margin will create some space around the element, which would also push the other elements away a bit, which would give you the "gap" between divs. If you want 5px of space between the divs, just set the style:

```
.myFloat {
    margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! And there wasn't any other code to provide that was relevant. And based how quick it took to fix it, not surprised! :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you need is padding. I'm using padding 10px on most divs i have which contain only text.

```
.textdiv{
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ra63X/